# Как получить минимальное значение атрибута и ноду в neo4j

Tags: nosql, cypher, neo4j

Агрегатная функция min возвращает нам минимальное значение из набора

```
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN min(n.property)
```

Представим условие, что у персоны есть от одной до нескольких машин,
Нам необходимо получить персоны с машинами у которых самая минимальная стоимость:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_many]->(c:Cars)
RETURN p, min(с.price)
```

Так мы получим почти то, что нам нужно, но нам бы еще получить сам авто. Вот тут загвоздка.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_many]->(c:Cars)
RETURN p, min(с.price), c
```

Так не работает. А еще веселее, если несколько авто у владельца с одинаковой стоимостью.
Я пробовал разные варианты.. пока застопорился на этом

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_many]->(c:Cars)
WITH p, min(c.price) as minPrice
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_many]->(c:Cars)
WHERE c.price = minPrice
RETURN p, c
```

Но пока не придумывается, как сгруппировать одинаковых Person в результате выдачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для того чтобы сгруппировать одинаковые лица необходимо добавить агрегат collect() к машинам:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_many]->(c:Cars)
WITH p, min(c.price) as minPrice
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_many]->(c:Cars)
WHERE c.price = minPrice
RETURN p, collect(c) as cars
```